# Encrypt a docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, password-protection, docx4j

I am trying to enforce permission for a docx file using **docx4j api**.

A `docx` file has 2 options for document protection.

**1.Restrict editing(required password to change the file)**

To restrict read/write access I tried following and it worked.

```
CTDocProtect.setEdit(STDocProtect.READ_ONLY);
CTDocProtect.setEnforcement(true);
```

**2.Encrypt a password(required password to open file)**

Is there a way to do this using docx4j or any other java api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) api . It has option to set read only protection.